# Specify path of a file in a Class Library, a method in that class library called from console application

Tags: dll

I have a ClassLibrary Project which is my business layer - Demo.Business

For this class library,

```
I have folder in the class library as below
                TRT
                 |
                TRT.cs
                TRTDetails.cs
                TRTFiles(Folder)
                 |
                **TRTFile.txt**
```

In TRT.cs class i have a method

```
public void UpdateDetails()
{
   var typeSeq = from val in TRTDetails.Read**(@"TRTFile.txt")**
}
```

Now i have added reference of this class library "Demo.Business.dll" to my console application - "DemoProcess.exe".
In the above Console Application I am calling the method **"UpdateDetails()"** as follows:

```
public void CallMethod()
{
   UpdateDetails();
}
```

How can I specify the path of the file "TRTFile.txt" in the method "UpdateDetails()" in class library?

I tried using System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName

```
(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Which always gives the path of executing application.
i.e

```
C:\\Projects\\Demo.Process\\bin\\Debug
```

How can i get the path as

```
C:\\Projects\\Demo.Business\\TRT\\TRTFiles............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

I.
This can be done using relative path. If your's `dll` is also situated in `Debug` folder, the following `path = @"..\..\..\Demo.Business\TRT\TRTFiles\"` will do the work.

First `..\` will get us to `C:\\Projects\\Demo.Process\\bin\\`. 
Second `..\` will get us to `C:\\Projects\\Demo.Process\\`. 
Third `..\` will get us to `C:\\Projects\\`.

II.
Or by using classes used for writing visual studio extensions ([Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.aspx) namespaces, etc.), they provide functionality to get all information about your project and it's content. But it's complicated.